# Excel Reformatting CSV lists in CSV to Text adding commas

Tags: excel

EDIT: It appears that the problem is actually stemming from the import itself.

I'm importing CSV data into excel in the format

```
87756316,193744,02/28/2017 11:59:00 PM,41.97,1.26,0.13,Sale - 200031654,,,,71.61.75.45,https://www.modcloth.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-modcloth-Site/default/COSummary-Submit,DEAL-342688,,2017-02-28 23:59:00.48,2017-02-28 00:00:00.0,11:56:28 PM,,0.0,,,2017-05-20 00:00:00.0,Sale,Personalized Commission Rules,"147144,140641","5.99,29.99","2,1",200031654,,New Customer Offer: 20% Off Your Entire Order,Deal Link,,,,"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.4.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14D27 Safari/602.1","   ",0.0,1,0,
```

Where as you can see there are a few comma-separated lists like

```
"147144,140641"
```

These are being reformatted upon import to excel as

```
147,144,140,641
```

Obviously this is an issue but I can't seem to find any formatting option that interprets these items without causing errors like this. Any thoughts would be really appreciated!

Thanks, 
Alex

Comment: In the import wizard change the type from general to text for those columns

Comment: MAN. Duh. Thanks for the tip. I already found a workaround by importing them a different way but that's brilliant. Thank you :)